# If $p$ prime and $0<x<y<z<p$ with squares congruent mod $p$, then $x+y+z\mid x^2+y^2+z^2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If $p$ is a prime number and $x,y,z\in N$ such that $0<x<y<z<p $ and $x^2, y^2, z^2$ give the same remainder when divided by $p$, then $ x^2+y^2+z^2$ is divisible by $x+y+z$ ?

Any advice to solve this problem?

Comment: If $0 < x < y < p$ and $x^2 \equiv y^2 \pmod{p}$, then $x+y = p$, so there is no such triple $x,y,z$.

Comment: The hypotheses seem impossible: there can be at most two square roots of an integer mod $p$.

Answer (score 3):

If $x^2\equiv y^2\pmod p$ then $p$ divides $y^2-x^2=(y-x)(y+x)$. By assumption, $0<y-x<p$, hence $p\nmid y-x$ and $p|x+y$. Again from $0<x<y<p$, we conclude $0<x+y<2p$, hence $x+y=p$. By the same argument, $x+z=p$, hence $y=z$, contradicting the assumption $y<z$.

Comment: `a\mid b` and `a\nmid b` give $a\mid b$ and $a\nmid b$, with better spacing than | and a better shape for $\nmid$.